# SQL incorrect syntax near '+'

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, concatenation

I have a simple select statement in MySQL written below. It keeps giving me a syntax error for the first `+` sign in the concatenation and I cannot figure out why. I also tried using the *concat* function and an error occurs as well.

```
select 1.VendorID, 1.VendorName, 1.VendorContactFName + " " + 1.VendorContactLName as Name
from Vendors as 1 JOIN
     Vendors as 2
     on 1.VendorID <> 2.VendorID and
        1.VendorContactFName = 2.VendorContactFName
order by Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use numbers as table aliases.  Second, to concatenate strings, use `concat()`.  Third, single quotes are the normal delimiter for strings.

So:

```
select v1.VendorID, v1.VendorName,
       concat(v1.VendorContactFName, ' ', v1.VendorContactLName) as Name
from Vendors as v1 JOIN
     Vendors as v2
     on v1.VendorID <> v2.VendorID and
        v1.VendorContactFName = v2.VendorContactFName
order by Name;
```

Comment: The alias name was the problem thank you

Comment: Re *"don't use numbers as table aliases"*: Perhaps include the reason in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the [concat function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) instead:

```
CONCAT(1.VendorContactFName, ' ', 1.VendorContactLName) as Name
```

It might be what you need.  But I think it will return null if any of the parameters are null.